# How can I write a GNU Makefile that has multiple target/prerequisites to execute the same recipe?

Tags: gnu-make

As an example:

```
a:b
        cp $< $@
c:d
        cp $< $@
e:f
        cp $< $@
```

One solution would be to use a function:

```
define my_cp
     cp $(1) $(2)
endef
a:b
        $(call my_cp, $<, $@)
...
```

But I was wondering if people could suggest an alternative ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `call` thing seems more complex than necessary.  You could just use:

```
CP = cp $< $@

a:b
        $(CP)
...
```

You could also do this:

```
a c e:
        cp $< $@
a: b
c: d
e: f
```

That's about it though.

Comment: The second example was exactly what I was looking for.  (the `cp` was just a contrived, overly simplified example recipe).